# Why does my global variable become nil?

Tags: ruby, global-variables, jruby

I'm writing a game engine with JRuby, and something goes wrong when I use a global variable. I have only these scripts:

main.rb:

```
$CLASSPATH << "src.rb" 

require 'modules'
require 'SceneMenu'
require 'SceneMap'

$game.setScene(SceneMenu.new)
```

modules.rb:

```
$game = Java::MyNamespace::Game::getInstance

module MyGame
  def self.cache 
    return $game.cache   # << ERROR OCCURS HERE
  end
end
```

SceneMenu.rb:

```
class SceneMenu
  def initialize 
    @count = 0
  end
  def update
    if @count == 100
      $game.setScene(SceneMap.new)
    end
    @count += 1
  end
end
```

SceneMap.rb:

```
class SceneMap
  def initialize 
    @logoTexture = MyGame::cache.load("mylogo.png")
  end
end
```

My problem is that when I launch the game, it always is fine, but when my `@count` reaches 100, and `SceneMap` is created, an error occurs saying:

```
undefined method 'cache' for nil:NilClass
```

while I have called `$game.setScene( ... )` just before.

I do not modify my `$game` variable at all, so I don't know what happens.

Does someone have an idea of what is going on?

Comment: which kind of error you've got?

Comment: A if you mean the message, it's : `undefined method 'cache' for nil:NilClass`. Otherwise, what do you mean by kind of error ?

Comment: This rises because you twice executes `getInstance`. You can also validate classes of `$game` with `$game.class`.

Comment: In fact I don't do it, I made a mistake copying my code, I have just edited to correct it.

Comment: validate `$game.class` just after the assignment, and before `$game.cache`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally fixed my problem by writing:

```
module MyGame
  def self.game
    return Java::MyNamespace::Game::getInstance
  end
end

$game = MyGame::game
```

Comment: I am not allowed to do it before tomorrow. But I will.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try changing the code to:

```
$game = Java::MyNamespace::Game::getInstance

module MyGame
    def cache 
        return $game.cache   
    end
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the way I wrote it ($game.getInstance.cache or $game.cahce). I will check that at the end of the day thank you.

Comment: So, what I wrote is : `def cache 
        return $game.cache   
    end`.